# Is there a way I can safely check to see if an assembly CAN be loaded before I actually do so?

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection, dll, .net-assembly

I am working on some software that will dynamically build menu items for certain dlls so that we can load components in dynamically based on what dlls are available on the users machine. Any dlls that I want to load have been flagged with an Assembly Attribute in the AssemblyInfo.cs file and how I determine whether or not I want to build a menu item for that dll. Here is my method so far:

```
private void GetReportModules() {
        foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())) {
            if (Path.GetExtension(fileName) == ".dll" || Path.GetExtension(fileName) == ".exe") {
                System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(fileName);
                object[] attributes = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ReportNameAttribute), false);
                if (attributes.Count() > 0) {
                    ReportNameAttribute reportNameAttribute = attributes[0] as ReportNameAttribute;
                    Type type = assembly.GetType(reportNameAttribute.BaseType);
                    MenuItem customReportsMenuItem = new MenuItem();
                    customReportsMenuItem.Header = reportNameAttribute.ReportName;
                    ReportsMenuItem.Items.Add(customReportsMenuItem);
                    customReportsMenuItem.Click += (s, ev) => {
                        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                        type.InvokeMember("Show", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj, null);
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For the most part its working fine, I am getting the dlls that I am expecting back out and am creating my menu items fine. The problem is that in order to check for the attribute I first need to load the assembly using Reflection. Some of the other local dlls are throwing errors when I try to load them about missing dependencies or he module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. Is there a way I can safely check to see if an assembly CAN be loaded before I actually do so? (sounds stupid as I write it out). Any thoughts on the problem I'm running into or better suggestions for how to accomplish what I'm trying here? Feeling a little bit in over my head.

Comment: I generally try to put Plugin assemblies in their own subfolder under the app path.  This way I can enforce that all DLLs in that directory should be valid for Assembly.Load and therefore an exception in loading is an indication of a real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a separate [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx), try to load the assemblies there, send the results back, and unload the AppDomain. This way you do not change your current AppDomain with 'garbage' of any loaded assemblies.

Comment: Is it possible to access the Assembly Attributes without having to load the assembly using reflection first? Then I can just check for the flag and only load ones which I know are relevant to the work I want to do

Comment: Thanks after quite a bit of research I actually got things really nicely implemented using AppDomains

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to make use of a try catch block. If it throw's an exception, you're not interested...

EDIT:

MSDN explains clearly the type of exceptions LoadFrom can throw. FileLoadException looks likely in your case.

I'm sure there is code out there that carried on after a catch. For example a logging framework. I would not want my framework to catch an exception and make my executable stop etc, i'd want it to smother the exception. My application should not fail just because a line of log miss fired.

Comment: I already thought about that but it would definitely never fly in my workplace. Bad practice to code for something that you expect might fail, exceptions should be for when something unexpected happens. Boss is pretty strict about coding standards and best practices

Comment: @JesseCarter: Unless you have a way of making the DLL capable of loading in code, an exception would be an appropriate thing to throw, and if your code is already throwing exceptions when a DLL fails to load, then you could always let the exceptions go up the call stack if you can't handle them yourself.

Comment: One can be strict about coding standards and best practices and should be readily accept that this is the correct use of an exception - the assumption that the assembly can be loaded has turned out to not hold, and any code which can take remedial action due to this should be outside the scope of the code which works with the assembly.

Comment: I have a few other resources to tap into but if I can't find out a better solution I will approach the boss with this and see what he says.

Comment: If the boss still says no, how about if you made a separate executable whose sole job was to return a list of the loadable DLLs in a certain folder. That executable could contain the 'try load/catch exception' logic without you having to "pollute" your actual application with the exception handling. Maybe the boss would go for that......

Comment: The point of loading the dlls dynamically was not to bloat the software (which is of an important financial nature) so while thats a cool idea, again, I don't think the powers that be would go for it. I think there may be some existing libraries already part of our system I could potentially tap onto but they are pretty advanced and as I'm still a co-op student it feels a little above my pay grade :P If I can share anything about the solution I end up implementing I will post it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Unmanaged Metadata API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404384.aspx) or the Common Compiler Infrastructure Metadata API (http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/) as alternatives to plain reflection.